# how to looping DTO in array to get result arrayList?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jpa

I am new in Java and Spring
how to loop / get result for this

```
[
  WhatsappContatcsDTO(whatsappid = 11111111111, name = John Dee), 
  WhatsappContatcsDTO(whatsappid = 16315551234, name = Kerry Fisher)
]
```

because i get that result from query jpa via @Query?
i do like to get result object from those result query

i like to get result here when i hit my server :

```
[
 { name: "John Dee", whatsappid: "11111111111"},
 { name: "Kerry Fisher", whatsappid: "16315551234"} 
]
```

this is my service :

```
public List<WhatsappContactVO> allContacts() {
    List<WhatsappContactVO> finalResult = new ArrayList<>();

    List<WhatsappChat> resultPerKey = whatsappChatRepository.findAllContact();
    for(WhatsappChat data: resultPerKey) {
        WhatsappContactVO result = modelMapper.map(resultPerKey, WhatsappContactVO.class);

        finalResult.add(result);
    }

    return finalResult;
}
```

Comment: Do you need to transform your result to JSON?

Comment: yes @DmitriyPopov, the result is on above

Comment: If you want to transform your query result into JSON then have a look at a json mapper library such as Jackson or Gson. I'm sure one is already provided by some Spring module, just grab the documentation on which one it is and how to use it.

Comment: i use modelMapper but it doesn't work or maybe i wrote wrong code LOL

Comment: Do you need only to return JSON from your REST controller, or you need this transformation for some server internal action?

What me and other commentor are trying to do is to formulate a concrete question. If something fails wit `ModelMapper`, post your code (better with minimum reproducible form) and the full error.

Comment: the result of query i get is that DTO in array and the result i want is the array of object i share in the last code , the error of modelmapper is just like this : ModelMapper mapping errors:\n\n1) Failed to instantiate instance of destination com.WhatsappChat.WhatsappContactVO. Ensure that com..WhatsappChat.WhatsappContactVO has a non-private no-argument constructor.\n\n1 error"

Comment: another error is : DTO cannot be cast to that ENTITY/Domain  @DmitriyPopov
look i write the service on above

Answer (score 1):

Create Converter which will convert your WhatsappChat to WhatsappContactVO as below example.

```
    @Component
    public class WhatsappContactVOConvertor implements Converter<WhatsappContactVO, WhatsappChat> {
    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     */
    @Override
    public WhatsappContactVO convert(final WhatsappChat whatsappChat) {
        final WhatsappContactVO whatsappContactVO = new WhatsappContactVO();
        whatsappContactVO.setWhatsappid(whatsappChat.getwhatsappid());
        whatsappContactVO.setName(whatsappChat.getName());

        return whatsappContactVO;
    }
 }
```

Initialize below conversionservice.

```
@Autowired
private ConversionService mvcConversionService;
```

Required Spring classes under package

> org.springframework.core.convert

Now You have to use this mvcConversionService to convert your WhatsappChat to WhatsappContactVO as per below

```
public List<WhatsappContactVO> allContacts() {
    List<WhatsappContactVO> finalResult = new ArrayList<>();

    List<WhatsappChat> resultPerKey = whatsappChatRepository.findAllContact();

      finalResult = resultPerKey.stream().map(result-> mvcConversionService.convert(result, WhatsappContactVO.class))
                        .collect(Collectors.toList());


    return finalResult;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 Class A
       {
       private String name;
       private String whatsappid;
       }
       List<WhatsappContatcsDTO> exList=dao.getInformation();
       List<A> newList=exList.stream().map(e->Converter.convert(ex)).collect(Collectors.toList());
String json=DTOToJsonConverter.convertDTOToJsonString(newList);
    public class DTOToJsonConverter 
{
    public static String convertDTOToJsonString(List<A> list) {
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        String json = gson.toJson(list);
        return json;
    }
```

returning JSON from list of DTOs

Comment: Converter is converting each WhatsappContactsDTO to class A object and as you need to transform your result to JSON you can use Gson.

Comment: is the result like i wish ??

Comment: This is what I have done in my project,feel free to implement it and tell me whether the result is what you wished for,I think it is.

Answer (score 0):

**You can use Modelmapper with TypeToken.**

`List<WhatsappChat> resultPerKey = whatsappChatRepository.findAllContact();`

`List<WhatsappContactVO> finalResult = new ArrayList<>();`

`finalResult = new ModelMapper()
.map(resultPerKey,new TypeToken<List<WhatsappContactVO> >(){}.getType());`

Comment: is TypeToken from modelMapper??

Comment: Yeah..! it belongs to modelMapper.